Stuck on Memtest screen
I am no expert at computers,  but I have started learning. But I'm a noob.
Here's the scoop. I bought an old 2013 imac.
Wiped the software and made the OS ubuntu 20.04
I've used this for months no problems.
I had the brilliant idea last night to try to update my 3d printer with making a file on visual studios
Visual studios told me i needed python 3.6 to proceed.
So me not knowing anything googled how to get it. Which in turn made me delete 3.12 python. And caused a sh**t load of errors, as in me trying to sudo update and a whole bunch of stuff I followed online.
When I restarted. Update software didn't work and terminal didn't work. But uxt worked enough.
I then did research and couldn't figure out how to reinstall 3.12.
After staying up half the night I got 3.12 and set it as default but now I have other system errors.
I followed another procedure and now when I restart it's at a memtest blue screen which after about an hour passes. But the issue now is the Bluetooth keyboard won't connect. So I cannot exit the screen when it passes. And when I reboot the computer it goes right into the same memtest screen.
What could I do here ? I would like to clean install Ubuntu I have on a flash drive. But my keyboard now doesn't connect. Thanks guys

If you think the answer works please accept it.

You messed with the heart of Ubuntu, Python.
Time to reinstall. You can not change the default version of Python the version that came with whatever the version of Ubuntu you are using came with and still have a fully working system.
If you need a different version such as this very old version mentioned in your question you can create a VM of an older version of Ubuntu that uses that version or learn how to have multi versions of Python without CHANGING the default.
The app should not have asked for this old version. Where did you get this app from?

I got visual studios from the app store that came with ubuntu.

Still makes no sense I just checked Ubuntu 20.04 came with Python 3.8 Anyway ignore for today and do the reinstall. After can see why it wants this old version. You sure it never asked for 3.8?

I swear it asked me for python 3.6

I'm stuck at the memtest screen though. My bluetooth keyboard won't connect so this is my first problem before anything else.

You need to boot from the USB or DVD media you installed from the first time. You must have had a working keyboard for that.

I always used this wireless keyboard but now at the memtest screen it says pass, and to press a random key " to remove this banner" but my keyboard light is flashing like it wants to pair lol one thing after another.

Power off put in the Boot USB and power up, you are doing a fresh install. The same as you did the first time you installed it.

I powered off plugged in the usb. And when it powers on goes right to the memtest. As it still has ubuntu 20.04 but it's stuck at this screen. I have the option to exit with the escape key. But the keyboard won't connect

Is there not a key or keys you can press after you apply the power and before any OS loads? I think there is. Otherwise borrow a cabled keyboard if you can.

That would work but my keyboard is stuck in pairing mode. It won't connect to the computer anymore lol i will have to see where i can find one. Do you know what keys need to be pressed upon startup? It's a 2013 IMac with the Apple OS deleted and just 20.04 ubuntu.

Got a keyboard was able to reboot. To grub command. And put In a code to reboot to make my os work again. But the problem i am having is when it reboots it defaults to gnu grub version 2.12 how do I make it so that reboot defaults to normal operation
